# Autohotkey: I can't get the path of the active file

Tags: autohotkey

**i want to get path of active file.**

**active file path**: C:\Users\e\Desktop\1w.jpg"

**autohotkey result**: C:\Windows\System32\dllhost.exe

code:

```
q::
WinGet, Path, ProcessPath, A
MsgBox, %Path%
```

Comment: windows photo viewer

Comment: and when I open a video it gives the path to the video player, not the path to the video (potplayer)

Comment: and run for ahk script not script path...  it just gives the program path (C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the path of the current active script:

```
F1::MsgBox, "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#prop

Get the path of the active file in windows photo viewer or in potplayer:

```
; Get the path of the recent items folder
RegRead, Recent, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders, Recent

F2::
    WinGetActiveTitle, active_title
    active_title := StrSplit(active_title," - Windows Photo Viewer").1
    active_title := StrSplit(active_title," - PotPlayer").1
    If FileExist(Recent "\" active_title ".lnk")
    {
        FileGetShortcut, %Recent%\%active_title%.lnk, path
        MsgBox, "%path%"
    }
    else
        MsgBox, path not found
return
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileGetShortcut.htm

Comment: Thank you very much it worked with the edit. But I need to add strsplit for each program    `q::
WinGetActiveTitle, a
a := (StrSplit(a," - Windows Photo Viewer").1)
FileCreateShortcut, %a%, %A_Desktop%\shortcuts\.lnk`

Comment: Yes. you need to add strsplit for each program.